# Internal S/PDIF connector on Gigabyte Z97 motherboard

Tags: audio, motherboard, surround-sound

I've ordered a Gigabyte GA-Z97-HD3 motherboard as part of a new system I'm building, here: http://www.gigabyte.com/products/product-page.aspx?pid=4955

Here's the back panel:
http://www.gigabyte.com/fileupload/product/2/4955/10138_big.png

The only audio outputs are individual speaker outputs, i.e. for a 5.1 arranegement, there's three 3.5mm jacks for Front pair, Back pair and Centre/Subwoofer.  On the last two systems I've built they've both had S/PDIF connectors (either optical or coax), and that's all that's on my surround sound receiver too.  The lack of a S/PDIF connector seems pretty common now, none of the motherboards I considered buying have one.  So to get 5.1 output it looks like I'd have to buy a new receiver.

The manual talks about an internal 2-pin S/PDIF connector, but it reads like it isn't intended to be piped out externally.  Here's what the manual says about it:

> SPDIF_O (S/PDIF Out Header)
>
> This header supports digital S/PDIF Out and connects a S/PDIF digital audio cable (provided by expansion
>   cards) for digital audio output from your motherboard to certain expansion cards like graphics cards and
>   sound cards. For example, some graphics cards may require you to use a S/PDIF digital audio cable for
>   digital audio output from your motherboard to your graphics card if you wish to connect an HDMI display
>   to the graphics card and have digital audio output from the HDMI display at the same time.
>
> For information about connecting the S/PDIF digital audio cable, carefully read the manual for your expansion
>   card.

But if all the connector is doing is providing an S/PDIF feed, is there any reason I can't get an S/PDIF backplate, plug it onto that jumper on the motherboard, and run a coax cable from it to my receiver?  I can't see why it wouldn't work but the manual doesn't describe the jumper being used in that way which is strange.

FYI will have a PCI Express/16 separate graphics card plugged into this, and my monitor is a Dual Link DVI connection, not HDMI, so I can't get sound out that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now I've had the motherboard arrive I can answer this myself - yes it does work :)  Did exactly as I hoped above, just plugged a jumper onto the S/PDIF connector on the board, ran it outside the case and to my surround sound system and Windows 7 was working properly with 5.1 sound immediately after install :)