# How to get optical out from Gigabyte 2 pin spdifo header

Tags: audio, motherboard, surround-sound, spdif

my question is identical to the one posted here:
[Internal S/PDIF connector on Gigabyte Z97 motherboard](https://superuser.com/questions/845028/internal-s-pdif-connector-on-gigabyte-z97-motherboard/851290#851290)

this user achieved what I want to do. I want to know HOW so that I can replicate the success. I have no idea what he means by "plugging a jumper" ..and what was on the other end of this jumper? what do I need to do that?

Comment: I built a TOSLINK output for my mobo years ago with a TOTX177L(F,T) transmitter, a capacitor, and an expansion slot bracket.  See https://www.sparkfun.com/products/retired/10204

Answer (score 1):

He installed a backplate like this:

[http://www.amazon.com/SPDIF-RCA-Plate-Cable-Bracket/dp/B0035J9Z7W](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0035J9Z7W)

This allows you to plug in an external audio cable instead of only passing the S/PDIF to another device inside the computer.

In the gigabyte forums they suggest that it works to use a 3 pin header and connect it to S/PDIF_out and ground only:

http://forum.giga-byte.co.uk/index.php?topic=136.0

This will supply the RCA jack, but not the optical output.

Comment: backplates like that appear to have 3 pins or more, with one being a +5v. How do I get something like that to work with 2 pin header that is just spdifo and ground?

Comment: That is actually covered in the amazon q&a section. They say they are drawing the 5v from an unused USB header on the board. Fair to say that this is "intermediate to advanced" level and you could destroy your MB and/or start a fire and burn your house down etc.

Comment: note also that that is an "optical" adapter. RCA is two-wire, so the optical part is probably where the 5v power and logic on the board is being used. I **think** you can skip power and make your own DIY if you want to use RCA

Comment: I skipped the DIY instructions, but yes, you can also completely ignore the commercial brackets and build your own. The 5V indeed is only required to power up the optical jack.

Comment: I want to use the optical jack. It looks like I'll need a backplate and 5V from unused pin. I'll speak to gigabyte support about this; Ideally i want them to suggest a solution that will work, I'm not an advanced user but maybe intermediate enough to do it on my own with guidance from the manufacturer. Just got this motherboard without realising "support for spdif out" does not mean one of the 3.5mm jacks doubles as an optical out (like my old laptop)

Comment: Returning the motherboard is no option?

Comment: I've already assembled the computer

Comment: Hi all, update: I bought something like this http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/41LmXhkvzpL.jpg and separated the jumper into ground and spdif, and power (spare usb2/1.1 headers). I've just connected it up and tested it with my receiver, changed default device to the digital audio device and tried a demo ac3 file in vlc with spdif on. it works well!   just a side note, while gigabyte support were responsive, they were not keen on providing a technical solution, i.e. "get this pcb and connect it up this way and it'll definitely work" oh well. thanks for all the advice